# Can't insert multiple INSERT queries via Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have simple multiple insert:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO `products` SET `code` = '0100130', `price` = '273.90', `brand` = 'Alpina', `supplier` = 'karat';
INSERT INTO `products` SET `code` = '0600075', `price` = '222.24', `brand` = 'Alpina', `supplier` = 'karat';
";
```

I have tried `DB::raw($query)`, `DB::query($query)`, `DB::statement($query)` - all three fails. But all three works if there is only one INSERT statement. If more than one, I get no error, but inserts are not performed.

I'm looking for a fastest way to import 13million inserts. Inserting one by one will take 24 hours for server.

Laravel v7.12.0

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO products(code, price, brand, supplier) VALUES
    (0100130, 273.90, 'Alpina', 'karat'),
    (0100130, 273.90, 'Alpina', 'karat')
";
```

You can't do two (or more) INSERT INTO into one sql query.

Comment: the more records you want to insert, the better above format is in my opinion. Uses less characters.

Comment: In your case it will be done once, I guess it's an import ? I think you should do it with the syntax above but running it every X rows (500 look good for me).